# Is stored procedure with Entity framework good design or have to write direct queries on front end (no stored procedure)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, data-access-layer

I am new to entity framework. Usually I have been using SQL Server stored procedure and make call using ADO.NET.

Now, I want to choose what is best to use as data access layer.

Is stored procedure with entity framework good design ? or have to do linq queries on model directly (no stored procedure). ?

I believe, stored procedure maintain all sql statements at common place and which can be manage later web deployment as well and this is not possible in case Ef makes direct queries to object

Please guide on design perspective what should choose.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

EF doesn't negate the values of a stored procedure, EF makes adhoc queries easier to perform as well as updates etc...  Stored procedures are still very useful, stored procs allow you to change logic/criteria without having to recompile the .NET code, from my experience EF makes life easier when you need to do a lookup on a foreign key etc but it is converted into a T-SQL statement.

Like everything it all depends, if you are in an environment where stored procedures are the norm then EF will work fine, however if you free to perform adhoc queries then EF expressions are great.  There is no right or wrong here, EF probably makes the number of stored procedures smaller but sometimes stored procedures are exactly what you should do.

The more logic you put in the DB then the more likely you'll call DB proc's.  Some people believe that the DB is where the business logic should exist, I am not one of those however.  I believe in a strong business layer in the application that simply uses the DB to store and recall information as well as report information.

From a performance perspective stored procedures will be the better direction, it's easier to debug/show plans on a stored procedure because you know exactly what is being called.  Set based database operations are better handled in SQL SERVER, that is the entire purpose of the RBMS, so all of these factors are at play when deciding what one should do.  I don't think it's realistic to outlaw stored procedures or EF expressions one way or the other.  **It's all about context.**

Comment: Thank you for all details. In my context, stored procedure will be helpful for production environment. Now, i will go with stored procedure then, data access layer should be ADO.NET (sqlhelper) OR have to achieve this using Entity Framework (with stored procedure) ?

Comment: Might as well use EF, I keep my EF generated classes in a dedicated assembly, I do not add any "Manager" classes to this assembly.  Remember to try and keep one DbContext object per web request, that would mean either passing the DbContext around or (more preferable) creating a your own RequestContext (at the Thread level) that creates the DbContext, that way you can get to the requests DbContext anywhere and keep the number of DbContext down.

Comment: Ok, I am just worrying, i will be using Stored procedure with EF. And EF generated SQL statement will not be used. will it make performance cost or i would go with ADO.NET. Please guide. can you also provide any link where provide some project architecture for EF with stored procedure. Thanks.

Comment: there's nothing to worry about... you can do either, curious why you aren't using the EF stored proedure wrapper?  Is it because it's legacy code?  You've got nothing to worry about.

Comment: Ok,Yes, worried for its generated code not going to use so. But, fine, i will use EF with databsae first approach and genereate model classes by selecting table and stored procedure. Thanks you for all details. I'll mark the answer. Just one thing, Can you also share me link/blog which i can follow/take some part for design project architacture haivng EF (stored procedure) and MVC. Just curious to know, what are the assemblies can be separaed from EF - Models, data access layer, manager classes, MVC -ViewModels/validations ?

Comment: I wouldn't do DB first, I would do code first.  With EF 4.0 you can do a Code first from an existing DB.  Generating simple POCO is simple and straight forward, here is a link to Scott Guthrie's link http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4